# Populate document.getElementById dynamically

Tags: javascript, wordpress, getelementbyid

I'm trying to automate a voting system with a check if voting exist sorta. The DOM retrive the ID of a shortcode and then the script do a loop to find the exact ID. Then if one shortcode is activated it proceed else if the id of the shortcode is undefined it show a message. I checked the script with a static way and it works, but when I try to make it dynamic there's something that doesn't work. I'm a beginner so maybe it's a dumb error.

```js
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 
//Getting the element using document.getElementById
var GravityFormCheck = document.getElementById("[id*='gform_wrapper_" + i+ "']")
//If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
if(typeof(GravityFormCheck) != 'undefined' && GravityFormCheck != null ){
        console.log('there are votes in progress');
    } else{
        //Show the message and hide the div of the shortcode
        document.getElementById("noVoting").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("Voting").hidden = true;
        console.log('there are NO votes in progress');
    }

}
```

```html
<section class="slice">
  <div id="voting" class="container-fluid">
  <!-- This is the shortcode example. They are all included in the html file so they can be activeted by a thirdpart application -->
  [gravityform id="other ids" title="false" description="true" ajax="true"]
<!-- This is the shortcode that generate the div below, I excluded all the other div's elements -->
  [gravityform id="2" title="false" description="true" ajax="true"]
<div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper gravity-theme" id="gform_wrapper_2" style="">
</div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="text-center">
  <h3 id="noVoting" hidden>The window for voting has concluded.</h3>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are asking. What do you mean you are trying to make it dynamic? and what was the static way?

Comment: Given `i = 0`, the `id` attribute you are seeking would literally be `[id*='gform_wrapper_0']` - I seriously doubt this is your intent. Rather, it appears you intent to have it resolve to `gform_wrapper_0`?

Comment: With the static way I have to insert the shortcode each time, and the only different change in the script is the absence of the loop and var GravityFormCheck = document.getElementById("gform_wrapper_2"). I would like to add all the shortcode at one and then activate or deactivate them with the third part application.

Comment: I think @RandyCasburn answered that. Try `document.getElementById('gform_wrapper_' + i)`

Comment: It still doesn't work. The else condition doesn't work and nothing happen when all shortcodes are disabled. I wonder why neither the console.log lines does not appear